# Python. Scrapy Xpath returning empty array

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using `scrapy` to scrape information from a website in `python` and I am only getting used to using Xpaths to find information.

I want to return a list of all the average ratings from **albums** of this artist from this page.
https://rateyourmusic.com/artist/kanye_west

To find the node for the albums I used `//div[@id="disco_type_s"]`
and I tried searching children for divs with the attribute `disco_avg_rating` using `div[@class="disco_avg_rating"]/text()`

Here is my function

```
def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
    item = rateyourmusicalbums() *ignore this

    for i in response.xpath('//div[@id="disco_type_s"]'):
        item['average rating']=i.xpath('div[@class="disco_avg_rating"]/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

Everything I try to get this list causes a problems. Usually it's more straight but this time I have to differentiate between albums and singles etc. so I am having troubles.

Appreciate your help, I am fairly new to web scraping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response.xpath('//div[@id="disco_type_s"]')` finds only one tag (this is what mostly happens when using `id` to match the xpath, they are unique). to get a list of selectors you should use something like:

`response.xpath('//div[@id="disco_type_s"]/div[@class="disco_release"]')` which will match multiple tags, so you can iterate on those.

then get the `average rating` with `'./div[@class="disco_avg_rating"]/text()'`

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.

```
def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
 for i in response.xpath('//*[@class="disco_release"]/div[3]'):
    item['average rating']=i.xpath('text()').extract()
    yield item
```

Comment: `extract_first()` is needed in order to avoid arrays.